# How to load jquery file in c# code using V8ScriptEngine (Clearscript)?

Tags: jquery, v8, clearscript

I am trying to execute javascript function from c# code using ClearScript(V8ScriptEngine). Here Script_Text is javascript code. I want to call api from jquery and load Execute function in C#.I got exception like $ is not defined.How can i load jquery in C# using clearscript(V8ScriptEngine)?

C# code:

```
public dynamic GetText(string Script_Text, List<object> paraList)
{
  V8ScriptEngine _v8Engine = new V8ScriptEngine(V8ScriptEngineFlags.EnableDebugging);     
 _v8Engine.Execute(Script_Text);
  object returnedVal = _v8Engine.Script.Execute();      
  return returnedVal;
}
```

Javascript Function:

```
function Execute(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',                
      url: "http://172.29.134.69:9006/api/Line/GetStationDefectsByStationIdstationId=1",
      success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        alert("Fail");
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could download and try to execute jQuery before running your script, but that would probably fail because the bare JavaScript environment lacks the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) that jQuery depends on.

You could provide a DOM implementation to underpin jQuery, but I suspect that would be a large effort, although there are public projects such as [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) that could help.

If `ajax` and `alert` are all you need, it would be much easier to implement them in C# or another .NET language and expose them for scripting.

Comment: It is not to use ajax or alert.I will upload javascript function in .txt file and execute it in C# dyamically.So please suggest me the way to write javascript function to call api and also how to load in C# and execute the function .

Comment: You can expose C# objects, types, delegates, etc. and use them from JavaScript; there's a ClearScript tutorial on GitHub. You just can't use jQuery easily because jQuery itself requires the DOM, which is usually provided by web browsers but isn't part of standard JavaScript.